# jQuery append() does not working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I am trying to append an image to DIV and it works on ALL major browsers EXCEPT Internet Explorer.

I am testing this on IE7. Maybe IE7 DOESN'T like to do append()?

Comment: Can you please share us some code

Comment: The description "not working" gives very little information about what's really happening. What happens, and how does that differ from what you expect? Do you get any error message? Is it actually appending the element that fails, or could it possibly be creating the image element that fails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure we need to see some code to give you good answer,
But since it is not working on just IE7 so I can smell that there is a missed closing html tag in the page or the html you are trying to append or append to.

Comment: Or perhaps an extra comma somewhere.

Comment: @PeeHaa: may be, but this should give js error, don't know if this what he got.

Comment: I found the problem.... IE doesn't like ` if(blockedTile.indexOf(ID_name) != -1) {` even though it works fine in Chrome and Firefox and other browsers...

Answer (score 1):

I remember I had similar issue in IE with append().
Try to use appendTo() instead
i.e.:

instead of:

```
parent.append(element);
```

use:

```
element.appendTo(parent);
```